# How to navigate to specified enum member with Resharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have enum with many members like below

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Item0,
    Item1,
    Item2,
    ...
    ItemN,
}
```

How I can navigate quickly to enum member by int value with ReSharper?